# Set individual permissions to folders in gcp cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a google cloud storage (bucket) with two folders (folder A and folder B).
I want to make folder A private and folder B public. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Storage operates with a flat namespace, which means that folders don't actually exist within Cloud Storage. The Cloud Console creates a visual representation of folders that resembles a local file browser.

**So the anwser to your question is "NO"**. Since the folders don't actually exist you can't make them public or private even using ACLs. You can only make the objects stored inside them as public or private using ACLs.

Much better way would be to create seperate buckets as folders and then make one bucket private and other public.

[Check more about cloud storage folders here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders#gsutil)